# Deploy Portlet via XMLACCESS remotly

Tags: xml, deployment, websphere, portlet

I'm trying to deploy a portlet with XMLACCESS remotely on an IBM Websphere application server. Everything works fine, I can export or delete pages.

At the moment I use the `<url>` Tag in my XML script to define the path where my `.war` file is stored which have to be deployed. But it looks like when I start my XML request on my client, the `.war` file wont be searched on my client, it will be searched on the server.

I dont want to copy the `.war` file to the server, I just want to start the task on the client. Is there a different tag, that automatically copies my `.war` portlet file to the server and deploys it?

I hope you guys understand my problem and maybe I can get some help.
Thank you,
Max

Answer (score 0):

According to the [XMLAccess FAQ](https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/dx/xmlaccess_frequently_asked_questions), copying WAR files to remote systems is not supported by XMLAccess.

Under question number 32: What are the limitations of XMLAccess?

> it cannot copy the portlet WAR files or theme files from one system to another